Where is the best place to ask questions about SMS/Mobile text messages?
I recently asked a question on WebApps Stack Exchange about issues with Google Forms links in mobile text messages being blocked sometimes, but it was closed as out of scope. Can anyone suggest the best place to ask this type of question regarding mobile text messages?

It would be better if we don't need to visit your webapps question to see what is actually asked ("blocking" of messages). This is also suggested in the tag wiki: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/site-recommendation/info Give an example question and title you want to ask. If you're going to be vague, it's not going to be the best advice and you may find yourself in rough seas.

Updated for context.

If we had an individual site for every individual problem, we'd have far too many sites.
So, ask at the next specific site:

For example, if this is happening on iPhone, ask on Ask Different.

If your phone is an Android, ask on Android Enthusiasts SE.



Just like we don't have a "Chrome SE site," nor a "Firefox SE site," no, we have Super User.
